# How to create Dashboards & widgets for Hierarchical queries in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs

How i can create Dashboards & widgets for Hierarchical queries (Work items and direct links & Tree of work items) in TFS 2013?

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is: you don't.

Even in (much) newer versions of TFS and Azure DevOps, this feature is only available for specific query shapes.

Comment: How can i create dashboards for different data if i am not able to build dashboards for tree/work items type queries? Is it only through excel? or any other options?

Comment: The SQL Server Report Server and Analysis Cube are still supported for 2013. But if you want to invest in reports, note that recent versions have deprecated that option and the recommended option is now to use the Analytics Service extension for TFS/Azure DevOps Server in combination with PowerBI. Or any other reporting platform you have available by connecting to the Analytics Service or the OData feed available in the recent versions.